# JPA return full foreign key entity on Insert/Update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

My goal is to be able to insert the below object with the user passing in the relevant data and the id of the foreign key, and return back to the user a full object that contains the full foreign key object as well, not just the foreign key id.

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Table(name = MY_OBJECT_TABLE)
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "MY_OBJECT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer myObjectId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ForeignObject.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOREIGN_OBJECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "FOREIGN_OBJECT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ForeignObject foreignObject;

    @Column(name = "FOREIGN_OBJECT_ID")
    private Integer foreignObjectId;

    @Column(name = "RANDOM_FIELD", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Boolean randomField;
}
```

I was trying with the above and it inserts but it only returns the foreignObjectId on insert and not the entire foreign object.

I tried the below to get it to work but no luck.

```
    @Transactional
    public MyObject create(MyObject myObject) {
        MyObject createdMyObject = this.myObjectRepository.save(myObject);
        return createdMyObject;
    }
```

and also tried

```
    @Transactional
    public MyObject create(MyObject myObject) {
        MyObject createdMyObject = this.myObjectRepository.save(myObject);
        return this.myObjectRepository.findById(createdMyObject.getMyObjectId());
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is something in my domain object I need to change or if I need to change my create method in some way.

Current output is:

```
{
  "myObjectId": 1,
  "foreignObject": null,
  "foreignObjectId": 3,
  "randomField": true
}
```

Expected output is:

```
{
  "myObjectId": 1,
  "foreignObject": {
    "foreignObjectId": 3,
  },
  "foreignObjectId": 3, // I don't care if this field stays here or not
  "randomField": true
}
```

Comment: is the transaction committed? Some fields of the object returned by JPA will only be set when the transaction in committed.

Comment: I believe because I'm using @ Transactional it only commits when it exists the method (or something like that).

Only way I could commit early judging by my quick google searches is going away from @ Transactional and instead managing the session/commits myself.

Comment: ... or you do the right thing and isolate persistence-operations in a DAO-layer, which is called by a Endpoint-layer. If the DAO-layer has the `@Transactional` annotation, the transaction will be committed by the time the object is returned to the Endpoint-layer.

Comment: I've done that. I have Controller => Assembler => DAO => Repository. When it gets back to the assembler the transaction is finished, but it still has null in that field. DAO contains the @ Transactional method above. Assembler takes the results and puts into the desired form before returning.

Comment: Then it is not a transaction problem.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the problem is. If it's a problem in the domain definition, or I need to do something different in the transaction so that I have the full foreign object returned back up the chain after an insert.

Comment: can you show the mapping on the ForeignObject side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following where you are corrupting your domain model to try and make it fit some front-end concern:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ForeignObject.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "FOREIGN_OBJECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "FOREIGN_OBJECT_ID", 
                       nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ForeignObject foreignObject;

@Column(name = "FOREIGN_OBJECT_ID")
private Integer foreignObjectId;
```

You are never setting the relationship but only the integer field.

This will not work as a call to `EntityManager#persist` (via myObjectRepository.save) simply takes the existing object and makes it persistent i.e. nothing is going to trigger setting the reference to ForeignObject.

```
@Transactional
public MyObject create(MyObject myObject) {

    //createdMyObject and  myObject are same instance  

    MyObject createdMyObject = this.myObjectRepository.save(myObject);
    return createdMyObject;
}
```

This will not work as the same instance (i.e. the one you created without the relationship set)  will simply be retrieved from the Hibernate's first level cache:

```
   @Transactional
    public MyObject create(MyObject myObject) {
        //createdMyObject, myObject and (due to 1st level cache) 
        //object returned from query are same 

        MyObject createdMyObject = this.myObjectRepository.save(myObject);
        return this.myObjectRepository.findById(createdMyObject.getMyObjectId());
    }
```

You can probable get method 2 to work by doing the following **however the correct solution is to remove the Integer field and have the relationship set correctly. A Spring MVC controller should automatically set the reference from the ID on POST/PUT request with `{... "foreignObject" : 3 ...}`**

```
   @PersistenceContect
   EntityManager em;

   @Transactional
    public MyObject create(MyObject myObject) {
        this.myObjectRepository.saveAndFlush(myObject);
        em.clear(); //force reload from database
        return this.myObjectRepository.findById(createdMyObject.getMyObjectId());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response! This helped me not only understand why what I was attempting was incorrect, but also what various options I had to work with.

Comment: I do find it odd that it isn't a common case that someone would create an object with a foreign key, and would want the full structure returned after created. (Main object + foreign key object structure)

Comment: after em.clear(); and get result again, why FetchType.EAGER is necessary? I've changed FetchType.LAZY, and it works!. BTW, your answer helped me a lot. Thanks.